# What is the difference between _uiState.asStateFlow() and StateFlow<UIState> = _uiState in ViewModel Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(AdaptiveHomeUIState(loading = true))
val uiState: StateFlow<AdaptiveHomeUIState> = _uiState
val uiState2 = _uiState.asStateFlow()
```

The above code shows two different public uiState. Which are uiState and uiState2. what exactly the difference between?, if it just the same. Which is the best recommended way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason we use a combination of mutable private state (`_uiState`) and a read-only public state (`uiState` and `uiState2`) is so that the consumers of the state cannot change the state.
In your particular example, these flows are most probably created inside a ViewModel and will be exposed to UI for consumption. We don't want the UI to be able to change the value in the `MutableStateFlow`, that's why we only expose a read-only `StateFlow`.

The difference between `uiState` and `uiState2` is that `uiState` can be converted back to a `MutableStateFlow` by type casting while `uiState2` cannot be. For example,

```kotlin
val flow1 = MutableStateFlow(1)
val flow2: StateFlow<Int> = flow1
println(flow1.value)
(flow2 as MutableStateFlow).value = 2  // Changing the value of `flow2`
println(flow1.value)
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

As you can see, one can change the value of `flow1` using `flow2` because they essentially point to the same object which can be seen in below example:

```kotlin
val flow1 = MutableStateFlow(1)
val flow2: StateFlow<Int> = flow1
val flow3 = flow1.asStateFlow()
println(flow1)
println(flow2)
println(flow3)
```

Output:

```
kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlowImpl@41629346
kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlowImpl@41629346
kotlinx.coroutines.flow.ReadonlyStateFlow@404b9385
```

So, it's better to use `.asStateFlow()` here.

Comment: I think the word "immutable" is ambiguous in general when it comes to flows. Also, if you upcast a Mutable_*anything*_ to a read-only version, that doesn't make it immutable. A List that is a MutableList that has been upcast is still mutable--it's just read-only to the user. "Immutable" is a guarantee that it will never change.

Comment: Anyway, I've been very curious about the existence of `asStateFlow()` and `asSharedFlow()`, since there is no counterpart for the Collection and Map interfaces. Everyone just relies on the fact that it is never truly safe to up-cast to a Mutable versions. By convention you can trust that if you pass a read-only List view of a MutableList out of your class, outside classes will not attempt to cast to MutableList and change it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yeah, your are right about the immutable thing. `StateFlow` is not really immutable but just read-only.

Comment: This answers the main question. Though I think this approach of preventing an explicit casting is unusual. Anyway, asStateFlow() returns " SharedFlow<T> by flow, CancellableFlow<T>, FusibleFlow<T>". Why? How can the extra interfaces help?