# what is the difference between _uiState.stateIn() and _uiState1.asStateFlow() in viewModel Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, kotlin-flow

In the following code, which shows two different public uiState handler, `uiState1` and `uiState`, what is the difference between the two scenarios?

```kotlin
// UI state exposed to the UI
// Scenario 1
private val _uiState1: MutableStateFlow<InboxUiState> = MutableStateFlow(InboxUiState.default)
val uiState1 = _uiState1.asStateFlow()

// Scenario 2
private val _uiState: MutableStateFlow<InboxUiState> = MutableStateFlow(InboxUiState.default)
val uiState = _uiState
    .stateIn(
        viewModelScope,
        SharingStarted.Eagerly,
        InboxUiState.default
    )
```

Comment: Looks like you asked the same question 2 months ago  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73987849/what-is-the-difference-between-uistate-asstateflow-and-stateflowuistate?rq=1

Comment: @YvesKalume It's not the same question. OP asked back then what are the implications of `.asStateFlow()`, here they're asking the difference between `.asStateFlow()` and `.stateIn()` operators.

Answer (score 2):

where *asStateFlow()* represents a modifiable state flow as a read-only *stateflow*, *stateIn()* him converts a *cold* **Flow** into a *hot* **StateFlow** that is started in the given coroutine scope.

The *stateIn* operator is useful in situations when there is a cold flow that provides updates to the value of some state and is expensive to create and/or to maintain, but there are multiple subscribers that need to collect the most recent state value.

**stateIn** : https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/state-in.html

**asStateFlow** : https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/as-state-flow.html